Spotlights Store.db File
Long story short... We have a user whose Notes app bit the dust and they lost everything. Years of work and personal information. No backup either. When we do a search for the notes in Spotlight, however, we can see them. Clicking on each note in Spotlight does nothing. Poking around we noticed this user’s store.db file has the related info in it, yet the file is gibberish. Is there a way to export this into something legible? We've read this may be something SQL or sqlite related. Hoping someone can help.

Spotlight has it indexed, but it doesn't have the full contents. I don't see this attack vector as being potentially successful.

But if we search in Spotlight we get the same results in this store.db file. Like we can see some of the text but not all. The rest is in like ASCII.
